# What's the difference between dato, nanode and kara?

Tags: grammar, words

I know they all indicate consequence. 
`kara` implies an opinion, while `nanode` is objective, but what is the exact difference between all three words?

Edit: Update with example:

**Example 1:  da to**

```
I think there should be more choice
motto sentakushi ga aru beki dato omoimasu.
```

**Example 2: na no de**

```
   Watching children's show is a good way to learn Japanese as the dialogue is simple.
    Kaiwa ga tanjun nanode, kodomo muke no bangumi wo miru nowa ii nihonngo gakushuu houhou desu.
```

**Example 3: kara**

```
….Therefore, this was my first thanksgiving.
...Desu kara korewa watashi no saisho no kanshasai deshita.
```

Comment: *Da to* is two words, and *na no de* is three words.  Each begins with a form of the copula (*da* and *na*), but the copula is missing from *da kara* in your list, so they can't be directly compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kara` and `node`'s meanings are same. `dato` doesn't mean because.

`kara` is used when a speaker says a speaker's own idea, and a speaker wants to tell that reasons to listeners briefly.

`node` is used when a speaker wants to explain existing, or exited situations. It is impact on listeners is weak.
So speakers commonly used when asking for permission, and tell a little gently apology.

---

Their usage obscured. So your examples are **ORIGINALLY** wrong, but now,  sometimes used the usage like that.

**UPDATE**: I wrote about `dato`.

Related: http://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2009/1206/280340.htm

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, but it doesn't match up with the examples I have seen. I have updated my post with the examples. In Example 1, `da to` is being used, even though it is the speaker's idea (which is what you say `kara` should be used for). In example 2, `na no de` is used even though again it is the speaker's idea. I am not saying that you are wrong, I am just a little confused on how to apply it. I am sure that I am just missing something obvious. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: @big_smile Their usage obscured. So your examples are ORIGINALLY wrong, but now, sometimes used the usage like that.

Comment: so does that mean the words are mostly interchangeable?

Comment: Grammatically, the words aren't interchangeable, but recently, sometimes be used to replace.

Comment: So it *can* be replaced, but it should *not* be replaced.